# Update a Slider Programmatically in Dojo

Tags: slider, dojo, dijit.form

i have a slider and i like to update the slider through a input field, i mean if i put a number in a input field and press a button , the slider update the position in the bar.

this is the code of the slider

```
       <li id="sliderHolder" class="leftPaneliconS">
                                    <div class="Slider" id="slider2" 
                                            data-dojo-type="dijit.form.VerticalSlider" 
                                            data-dojo-props='name:"vertical1", 
                        onChange:function(val){ hidesubmenu();zoomCanvas(val); }, 
                                                    value:50, 
                                                    maximum:100, 
                        minimum:20, 
                        pageIncrement:100, 
                        intermediateChanges: true, 
                        style:{height:"150px"} '>
                                            <ol data-dojo-type="dijit.form.VerticalRuleLabels" 
                                                    data-dojo-props='container:"leftDecoration", style:{width:"2em"}, labelStyle:"right:0px;"'>
                                                    <li></li>
                                                    <li></li>
                                            </ol>
                                    </div></li>

   <input id="update" name="update" value=" ">
```

i was trying this:

```
    zoomvar=document.getElementsByName("vertical1"); 
   zoomvar.value=newValue;
```

but that does not work. hope some can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try that : dijit.byId("slider2").set("value", yourValue);
Also, make sure you're calling that AFTER your slider has been started :)